# About export compliance of applications from the United States

Tags: ios, zip, app-store-connect

It seems necessary to upload French encryption declaration in iTunes Connect in the following cases:

> Your app uses an industry standard algorithm, not provided within the Apple operating system

[Question] Is a password protected zip file included in "industry standard algorithm"?